# What's the name of this "splatter" stroke typeface?

Tags: font-identification

I've seen this font on facebook and have been looking for this kind of font for a long time.

I've tried using online services to identify the font name but none of them could provide a correct answer.

[image: font]

Comment: I work with typefaces daily and have not seen this. Knowing who used it could help me understand if it would even be available, or if it was custom. You could freehand something that would be close. Setup guides, pick the correct size and texture of paint brush and give it a go.

Comment: I already got an answer, but I've found this on [Vellu's facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Vellusta?fref=ts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is highly suggestible for [TRUE LIES](http://www.dafont.com/true-lies.font)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, looks like the right font to me. Apart from some letters such as the `R` have been edited